# syntax error with sqlite3_exec in C, but works fine in sqlite3 CLI program

Tags: c, sqlite, ubuntu, syntax-error

I am trying to develop a cross-platform C program that does simple SQLite database management. It simply creates some tables, triggers and then insert records periodically.

The issue I encountered is that I got syntax error trying to create a trigger programmatically by calling sqlite3_exec with the SQL command directly. What's funny is that my program works fine in Windows. It creates/drops trigger successfully. However while running on Linux (Ubuntu) I got the following syntax error.

```
Info: connecting device...
Info: Opened database ./test.db successfully
Info: operation done successfully
Error: Time:Fri Feb 24 17:22:29 2017 File:/home/stephen/code/IoTGW/azure-iot-gateway-sdk_0222/modules/sqlite/src/sqlite.c Func:sqlite_exec Line:315 SQL error: near ",": syntax error
Error: Time:Fri Feb 24 17:22:29 2017 File:/home/stephen/code/IoTGW/azure-iot-gateway-sdk_0222/modules/sqlite/src/sqlite.c Func:sqlite_exec Line:317 Error Query: @CREATE TRIGGER MODBUS_size_control INSERT ON MODBUS WHEN (select count(*) from MODBUS)>10
BEGIN
DELETE FROM MODBUS WHERE (ADDRESS,MAC,DATETIME) IN (SELECT ADDRESS,MAC,DATETIME FROM MODBUS ORDER BY DATETIME limit (select count(*) - 10 from MODBUS));
END;@
```

*note that the `@` symbol is added just to make sure I didn't include some silly invisible value in the SQL command. `@` is not part of the SQL command executed by sqlite3_exec.

Except than that, the other insert operations work just fine.

Another weird thing is that I ran the exact same SQL command which caused the error in the sqlite3 shell program. It works just fine.

After creating the trigger in sqlite3 shell. I ran my program again, it gave me a totally different error.

```
Error: Time:Fri Feb 24 17:52:49 2017 File:/home/stephen/code/IoTGW/azure-iot-gateway-sdk_0222/modules/sqlite/src/sqlite.c Func:sqlite_exec Line:315 SQL error: malformed database schema (MODBUS_size_control) - near ",": syntax error
Error: Time:Fri Feb 24 17:52:49 2017 File:/home/stephen/code/IoTGW/azure-iot-gateway-sdk_0222/modules/sqlite/src/sqlite.c Func:sqlite_exec Line:317 Error Query: @CREATE TRIGGER MODBUS_size_control INSERT ON MODBUS WHEN (select count(*) from MODBUS)>10
BEGIN
DELETE FROM MODBUS WHERE (ADDRESS,MAC,DATETIME) IN (SELECT ADDRESS,MAC,DATETIME FROM MODBUS ORDER BY DATETIME limit (select count(*) - 10 from MODBUS));
END;@
Error: Time:Fri Feb 24 17:52:51 2017 File:/home/stephen/code/IoTGW/azure-iot-gateway-sdk_0222/modules/sqlite/src/sqlite.c Func:sqlite_exec Line:315 SQL error: malformed database schema (MODBUS_size_control) - near ",": syntax error
Error: Time:Fri Feb 24 17:52:51 2017 File:/home/stephen/code/IoTGW/azure-iot-gateway-sdk_0222/modules/sqlite/src/sqlite.c Func:sqlite_exec Line:317 Error Query: @INSERT INTO MODBUS(VALUE,ADDRESS,MAC,DATETIME) VALUES(09221,40002,'01:01:01:01:01:01','2017-02-24 17:52:51');INSERT INTO MODBUS(VALUE,ADDRESS,MAC,DATETIME) VALUES(29113,40001,'01:01:01:01:01:01','2017-02-24 17:52:51');@
```

As shown, even the previously working insert commands no longer work anymore. Seems that the trigger is causing all the problems. But I just don't see why. It works on Windows, works on Ubuntu in sqlite3 shell. Even if I insert records from sqlite3 shell after the trigger is created, it works fine.
Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: That is not minimal.

Comment: Sorry I don't have my development machine now. I'll try to create one soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is documented in the [SQLite Documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

#### Syntax Restrictions On UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT Statements Within Triggers

The UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT statements within triggers do not support the full syntax for UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT statements. The following restrictions apply:

- The ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses on UPDATE and DELETE statements are not supported. ORDER BY and LIMIT are not normally supported for UPDATE or DELETE in any context but can be enabled for top-level statements using the SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT compile-time option. However, that compile-time option only applies to top-level UPDATE and DELETE statements, not UPDATE and DELETE statements within triggers.

You are using a LIMIT-Clause in the DELETE statement of your trigger:

```
DELETE FROM MODBUS 
    WHERE (ADDRESS,MAC,DATETIME) IN (SELECT ADDRESS,MAC,DATETIME FROM MODBUS 
    ORDER BY DATETIME
    limit (select count(*) - 10 from MODBUS));
```

The error message is somewhat misleading, however.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So I might have the SQLite libraries and SQLite3 shell program built in different compile-time option.

Comment: @S.C According to the documentation it should even _never_ work inside a trigger.

Comment: Right, but somehow it works in Windows platform and SQLite shell program in Windows. I'll rewrite the queries to obey the rules.